# What is the difference between combinereducer and AcitonreducerMap?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

Can anyone explain the difference between ActionReducerMap and Combinereducer?

Comment: Why are you asking?  What are you actually trying to accomplish and/or learn?

Answer (score 0):

CombineReducer & ActionReducerMap are 2 completely separate things.
ActionReducerMap is the type of an Object where every key is a reducer.

combineReducers for example expects an ActionReducerMap.

What combineReducers does can be read here: https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers

Comment: I already saw this comment somewhere but need more in detail